# Which PDF Support Chinese Language In Magento?

Tags: pdf

Which PDF Support the Chinese Language In Magento?

**We need to send Chinese order email from Chinese store of Magento.**

so please suggest me which PDF support?

Comment: You have to add fonts which supports Chinese language to pdf library to print Chinese fonts.

Comment: @KumarM thanks for reply

Please Suggest me which font for Chinese language and how to set in TCPDF?

Comment: You can see more details here : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1508

Comment: @Kumar We already use this but not getting any solution.